# Does Thread.sleep() prevent a StackOverflow error?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Would the following code eventually throw a StackOverflow error?

```
public class TestStackOverflow {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        recursion();
    }
    public static void recursion() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch(Exception err) {}
        recursion();
    }
}
```

It seems that the `Thread.sleep(100);` prevents the StackOverflow error but I am wondering if overtime a StackOverlow error will be thrown? And why does slowing the recursion prevent it? I guess I am mostly unsure of what a StackOverflow is and why this seems to stop it?

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc of `Thread.sleep(..)` and `StackOverflowError`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I am not sure what you mean by the comment above.

Comment: Start by reading the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long) and  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels he means "have you read the manual?". Do you even know what they (`Thread.sleep` and `StackOverflowError`) are?

Comment: Stack overflow is not prevented but is slower to come, that is all; you do a _lot_ of recursive calls in 100 ms.

Comment: @immibis: the above question doesn't imply that he does not know what they are. The OP is observing something and cannot explain it. The API's don't explain it either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Thread.sleep` cannot prevent a `StackOverflowError`.  It doesn't take stack frames off the stack.  All it will do is postpone the error.  Each method calls takes up stack memory.  By making a recursive call without stopping, all this program will do is take up more stack memory with each call, eventually filling it up and causing the error.

Taking out `Thread.sleep` produces the error almost immediately.

Changing it to `Thread.sleep(1);` (sleep for 1 ms at a time) makes the program take about 11 seconds to produce the error on my machine.

Answer (score 7):

> Does `Thread.sleep()` prevent a StackOverflow error?

No.

> Would the following code eventually throw a StackOverflow error?

Yes.

> It seems that the `Thread.sleep(100);` prevents the StackOverflow error

Why?

Comment: Ah... Thanks. I knew that it keeps creating frames to the stack I was just wondering that since it is doing it at a "slower" rate that it wouldn't be thrown. Thanks for clarifying.